# React Native - Sticky footer at the bottom of container

Tags: flexbox, react-native

I'm trying to make a `<View>` called `footer` stick at the bottom of the `right` container.

Here is a live example:
https://rnplay.org/apps/G3rHqQ

If I make the left container higher than the right one then it won't work. If the right container is higher than the left one then it works....

[image]

The red and orange elements are dynamic, have different height depending on their content. The blue one, instead, should always stick to the bottom of the right container.

I have also tried with `position: 'absolute'; bottom:0; left: 0; right: 0;` and it does stick to the bottom but only IF the right container is higher than the left one.

Comment: can you post a picture of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks, I have added an image to the description.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to set a flex:1 on the outermost container to get the flex properties working the way you want. I've set up a working project [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/WoceXg) and pasted the code below as well.

https://rnplay.org/apps/WoceXg

```
'use strict';

import React, { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';

const SampleApp = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex:1 }}>
        <View style={styles.wrapper}>
          <View style={styles.left}>
            <Text>Left</Text>
            <Text>Left</Text>
            <Text>Left</Text>
            <Text>Left</Text>
            <Text>Left</Text>
            <Text>Left</Text>
            <Text>Left</Text>
            <Text>Left</Text>
            <Text>Left</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.right}>
            <View style={styles.rightInner}>
              <View style={styles.content}>
                <Text>content</Text>
                <Text>content</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.footer}>
                <Text>Sticky</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex:1 }}></View>
      </View>
    );
  },
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  wrapper: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    paddingTop: 50,
    flex:1
  },
  left: {
    backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
    flex: 1,
  },
  right: {
    backgroundColor: 'lightgreen',
    flex: 4,
  },
  rightInner: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'orange',
  },
  content: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  footer: {
    backgroundColor: 'green',
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);
```

Comment: What you are doing with the `<View style={{ flex:1 }}></View>` is to occupy half of the space on the page and making the wrapper one stretch. By stretching the container becomes higher than the left one and causing the `footer` to go at the bottom. Try adding a background to that `View` and you will see that it takes the half bottom space.

Answer (score -2):

I'm trying to do something similar. I need a View to stick to the bottom. I used `poistion: 'absolute', bottom:0` and it does stick to the bottom but the width of the view does not stretch anymore.

Comment: I was using the same technique, with `position: 'absolute'; bottom:0; left: 0; right: 0;`. It works fine if the right container is higher than the left one. If it is shorter then the positioned absolute element will not respect the `bottom: 0;`. Could it be a bug in the Flexbox?

Comment: Not sure. I ended up having to put a ListView above the view I need to stick to the bottom and the ListView expands to fill the area anyway so my problem went away. Would still like to see an answer to this.

Comment: Was that an answer or a comment, please read StackOverflow guidelines to put your contribution in form of an answer or a comment